# Questions which have false conditions

Tags: logic, definition

There are many "questions" on the internet like

> If
>   $$1=5$$
>   $$2=6$$
>   $$3=7$$
>   $$4=8$$
>   then how many is $5$?

With one "logic" answer is $9$ because $n=n+4$, then $5=9$. With other "logic" answer is $1$ because if $1=5$ then $5=1$. Of course, these answers aren't correct because there are no number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n=n+4$.
However, is it possible to solve it mathematically? We can write this as a system of equalities:
$$1=5\land2=6\land3=7\land4=8\land5=x$$
and it will become
$$\operatorname{false}\land\operatorname{false}\land\operatorname{false}\land\operatorname{false}\land5=x$$
which have only solution $x\in\emptyset$.
So, can we say that this question have only solution $x\in\emptyset$, i.e. there is no number which satisfies the conditions? Or this question does not have answer because conditions are false?

Comment: This is not a mathematics question.

Comment: In many of these questions, people seem to confuse "$=$" with "$\mapsto$", or something like it. They could've also exploited the well-known notation for functions, and write $f(1) = 5$ and so on. You just have to accept that "people on the internet" or "people on facebook" in general never will get to grips with the strict and logical world that is mathematics and its notation, and think that when they mean "$1$ becomes $5$ according to the rule I'm thinking about", they can use "$=$" to signify that relationship. Or maybe they really are working modulo $4$.

Comment: Well as first it depends on what Set,ring,field are you solving this.For example if you're solving modulo 4 than those equations are true.But also if the $=$ is changed with $\to$ than this can be a function,and there are infinitely many function that satisfy those conditions etc.

Comment: @Arthur. I know that that they means $f(1)=5$ and I know that in this case there are infinitely many solutions because $f(5)$ can be any number, but I want to know can we answer this question if there are $1=5$ insead of $f(1)=5$.

Comment: @kingW3 Of course, the implicit understanding in any such question is always that you choose the _simplest_ function among all those that satisfy the given criteria (another part where the general populace disagree with mathematicians), where "simple" is in of course subjective, but few instructions are simpler than "add $4$".

Comment: If in the question "=" is replaced by ":=", then, obviously we have $5=1$ by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've usually seen the question at the end written as:
$$ 5 = \; ? $$

If you take the $=$ symbol literally at its usual meaning in these puzzles, 
then the puzzle statement is equivalent to solving for $x$ in

$$ (\mbox{false} \wedge\mbox{false}\wedge\mbox{false}\wedge\mbox{false})
\Rightarrow (5 = x)$$

which is vacuously satisfied by any value of $x$, since the left-hand side of
the implication is false.

What the puzzle is *intended* to mean is that we're to interpret the $=$ 
symbol as a (clearly non-reflexive) relation $\to$, and solve for $x$ in $5\to x.$
Alternatively, since the intended relation is usually a function, 
we could write $f(1)=5$, etc., and then solve for $x$ in $f(5) = x.$

It can be annoying to see the $=$ symbol abused this way
when a more appropriate symbol could just as well have been used.
But evidently the people posing these puzzles don't have experience with
symbols other than $<$, $>$, or $=$ to represent relations,
or they don't expect their audience to have such experience.
This has little to do with the quality of the puzzle, which may be trivial,
moderately interesting, or ill-conceived regardless of the notation in which
it's presented.

Comment: Any reason why $\mbox{false}\land\mbox{false}\land\mbox{false}\land\mbox{false}\land5=x$ isn't correct, but $(\mbox{false} \wedge\mbox{false}\wedge\mbox{false}\wedge\mbox{false})
\Rightarrow (5 = x)$ is correct?

Comment: @Mathematician171: The question says "**If** $1=5$ etc. **then** how many is 5?" -- and $\Rightarrow$ is how we usually interpret if-then.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to understand such questions is that the asker has never properly internalized what "$=$" means. (They have probably been *told*, but it didn't catch hold).

These askers appear to understand $A=B$ as meaning "$A$ becomes $B$, through some unspecified process". This understanding makes enough sense in many cases -- namely when $A$ is an arithmetic expression and $B$ is the canonical notation for its value -- that it is apparently possible to go through school without noticing that it is wrong.

So what the asker really means by the question is

> I'm thinking of some process.
>   When we apply it to 1 we get 5 back.
>   When we apply it to 2 we get 6 back.
>   When we apply it to 3 we get 7 back.
>   When we apply it to 4 we get 8 back.
>   What do we get back for 5?

Read this way, the question makes as much sense as any other continue-this-sequence question. It's just the asker who, out of ignorance, misuses notation when he tries to state it.

Comment: "It depends on what the definition of *is* is."  :)

Comment: @John: No, exactly not that. I'll bet the people we're speaking about here pronounce $=$ as "makes", not "is".

Comment: My comment had (mostly) humorous intent and was referring to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment_of_Bill_Clinton).  But, to be fair, I would read the sentence $1+2=3$ as "one plus two is three."